# Sums of two elements to prime powers in finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

For an algebra HW, I had to show that any element in a finite field can be written as the sum of two squares of elements in that same field (the problem comes from Judson). I was able to do that. I was wondering if this idea could be (ever, maybe only in certain cases) generalized to the sum of two elements to prime powers.

My first thoughts for beginning to prove this involved using the prime characteristic of a finite field and thinking of something similarly motivated to what is referred to as the "Freshman's Dream" in our textbook: for a finite field with prime characteristic $p$, then for field elements $a, b$ we have $$(a + b)^{p^n} = a^{p^n} + b^{p^n}$$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Obviously I can't use the theorem for any prime I want to. I was hoping there might be something else of note to prove/disprove this seamlessly. Does this only work for the prime that is our field's characteristic, or is there more to this?

Comment: For a finite field $F$ and a any whole number $n$ with $\gcd(|F|-1,n)=1$, every element $a\in F$ can be written as $a=x^n$ for some $x \in F$. This follows from the fact that the multiplicative group of a finite group is cyclic. It also follows that if $\gcd(|F|-1,n)=2$, every element $a\in F$ can be written as $a=x^n+y^n$. Not a very powerful generalization, but I thought it should be mentioned.

Comment: [The Cauchy-Davenport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Cauchy%E2%80%93Davenport_theorem) is somewhat similar in spirit to the proof that every element of a finite field is the sum of two squares. When $n\mid p-1$, the set of $n$th powers of $\Bbb{F}_p$ has $\approx p/n$ elements. So it won't give us full coverage with just two terms when $n>2$. However, it does imply that for every prime $p$ all the elements $a\in \Bbb{F}_p$ can be written in the form
$$a=x^2+y^3+z^5.$$